# Contradictiry values for the same calculation in python

Tags: python, numpy, numbers

Consider the following two results

```
import numpy as np

(1/21) * np.log( (1/21) / (3/21) * (3/21))
```

which results in

> -0.14497725893921062

and the same calculation as follows

```
import numpy as np

x  = 0.14285714285714285
y  = 0.14285714285714285
xy   = 0.047619047619047616

xy * np.log(xy / (x * y))
```

which results in

> 0.040347517161295414

Both calculations are same, but results has so much gap. What is the issue here?

And which one is recommended, if its not a subjective question?

Comment: [This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) might help you with understanding how Python manages numbers.

Comment: @hanugm you miss two brackets in first equation `((3/21) * (3/21))`

Answer (score 1):

Because multiplication and divison have same precedence at Python and Python reads them from left to right.

for example:

```
x, y, z = 2, 4, 8
```

these are completely different:

```
x / y * z == x / (y * z)
>>>False
```

left side is 4.0 and right side is 0.0625

ps:

> Parentheses have the highest precedence and can be used to force an expression to evaluate in the order you want.